# finding the largest element in an array using functions

Tags: c++, arrays

This is the question I've tried to attempt
"Given an array A[] of size n. The task is to find the largest element in it.

#### Input:

> n = 5
> A[] = {1, 8, 7, 56, 90}

#### Output:

> 90

#### Explanation:

The largest element of the given array is 90.
I'm unable to get the desired outcome, my output screen freezes. I think the problem is in passing by reference, please help me solve and understand my mistake

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int largest(int* arr[], int* n) {
  int max = 0;
  for (int first = 0; first <* n; first++) {
    if (*arr[first] > max) {
      max = *arr[first];
    }

  }

  return max;
}

int main() {
  cout << "enter how many numbers you want in an array = ";
  int userinput;
  cin >> userinput;
  int* myarray=new int[userinput];
  for (int loop = 0; loop < userinput; loop++) {
    cin >> myarray[loop];
  }
  cout << "Your array = { ";
  for (int loop = 0; loop < userinput; loop++) {
    cout<< myarray[loop]<<" ";
  }
  cout << "}";
  cout << endl;
  cout<< "Largest number in the array = "<<largest(&myarray,&
                                                   userinput);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass anything either by reference or by pointer.

Comment: BTW, [do not define the `std`` namespace globaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

- You should use the argument `arr` to read the array.
- You should use `=` operator, not `==`, to perform assignment.
- You should add indentation to make your code easy to read.
- Using fixed value for the initial value of `max` will make it produce wrong output when all of the elements of the array ls less than the initial value.

Fixed code:

```
int largest(int *arr[], int *n)
{
    if (*n <= 0) return 0;
    int max = (*arr)[0];
    for (int first = 0; first <* n; first++)
    {
        if ((*arr)[first] > max)
        {
            max = (*arr)[first];
        }

    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for quick response !  it worked ! ive noticed if i dont add ( ) in the *arr, my output screen freezes, why is that?

Comment: @codeplayer Because `[]` operator has higher precedence than unary `*` operator and removing `()` will lead to out-of-range access of the "one-element array" whose element is `myarray`.

Comment: Really try to use the std library containers (std::array, std::vector, std::list) instead of plain arrays. Code like this is more likely to contain bugs, like overshooting the boundaries of the array. And you can use the for(auto x : collection) syntax for safe enumeration over the elements in the collections.

Answer (score 1):

Most common problems already have a solution, in this case the standard library.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::array<int, 4> ar{ 1, 4, 42, 2 };
auto max_value = *std::max_element(ar.begin(), ar.end());
```

This will set max_value to 42.
In your case you could also use a std::vector instead of an array and push_back any entries the user entered.

```
std::cout << "enter how many numbers you want in an array = ";
int userinput{0};
std::cin >> userinput;
std::vector<int> values;

for (int loop = 0; loop < userinput; loop++) {
    int new_value{ 0 };
    std::cin >> new_value;
    values.push_back(new_value);
}

std::cout << "Your array = { ";
for (const auto value : values)
{
    std::cout << value << " ";
}

std::cout << "}";
std::cout << std::endl;

auto max_value = *std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());
std::cout << "Largest number in the array = " << max_value;
```